# MongoDB data disappeared after kernal panic in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

The DB disappeared after 2019-07-25T06:36:53.999+0900. Below is log file. I am just installing some ubuntu packages but there some problem like /boot foler disk space issues or not, the kernel disrupted and I tried to boot with recover mode, and then succeed it. But after booting, my mongodb data looks disappeared - If I access my website there should be some articles but I cannot find this articles - perhaps it disappeared.

What I did is ...  In grup selection window when access to ubuntu recovery mode, I choose "clean" one time and it looks like excuting `apt-get autoremove`. After I realize data gone, I typed `mongod --repair` one time. This two thing are all I did. Ah, I update ubutu version 3 days ago. But that time the db has no problem.

Where is my DB? Can you guess? I don't have backups so I am very confused.

```
2019-07-25T06:36:53.902+0900 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:35460 #1938 (9 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.930+0900 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:35461 #1939 (10 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.950+0900 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:35462 #1940 (11 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.952+0900 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:35463 #1941 (12 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.999+0900 I NETWORK  [conn1941] end connection 127.0.0.1:35463 (11 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.999+0900 I NETWORK  [conn1940] end connection 127.0.0.1:35462 (10 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.999+0900 I NETWORK  [conn1939] end connection 127.0.0.1:35461 (9 connections now open)
2019-07-25T06:36:53.999+0900 I NETWORK  [conn1938] end connection 127.0.0.1:35460 (8 connections now open)
2019-07-26T01:03:53.557+0900 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=854 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ubuntu
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-07-26T01:03:53.747+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2019-07-26T01:03:53.748+0900 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2019-07-26T01:03:53.750+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-07-26T01:03:53.750+0900 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2019-07-26T01:03:53.750+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2019-07-26T01:03:53.750+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-07-26T01:03:53.750+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-07-26T01:03:53.750+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-07-26T01:03:55.375+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564070635:375844][854:0x7f9600196a00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 4/38038144
2019-07-26T01:03:55.376+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564070635:376299][854:0x7f9600196a00], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 5
2019-07-26T01:03:55.452+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564070635:452166][854:0x7f9600196a00], txn-recover: Recovering log 5 through 5
2019-07-26T01:03:55.553+0900 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564070635:553501][854:0x7f9600196a00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-07-26T01:03:55.743+0900 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-07-26T01:03:56.093+0900 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-07-26T01:03:56.437+0900 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2019-07-26T01:03:56.440+0900 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2019-07-26T01:03:57.017+0900 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
```

**root@ubuntu:/data/db# ls -al**

```
합계 332
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096  7월 26 00:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096  7월 20  2018 ..
-rw------- 1 root root    46  7월 26 00:45 WiredTiger
-rw------- 1 root root    21  7월 26 00:45 WiredTiger.lock
-rw------- 1 root root  1044  7월 26 00:57 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw------- 1 root root 61440  7월 26 00:57 WiredTiger.wt
-rw------- 1 root root  4096  7월 26 00:55 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw------- 1 root root 32768  7월 26 00:55 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw------- 1 root root 16384  7월 26 00:55 collection-0-6981595682191946835.wt
-rw------- 1 root root 36864  7월 26 00:56 collection-2-6981595682191946835.wt
-rw------- 1 root root  4096  7월 26 00:55 collection-4-6981595682191946835.wt
-rw------- 1 root root 32768  7월 26 00:55 collection-7-6981595682191946835.wt
drwx------ 2 root root  4096  7월 26 01:00 diagnostic.data
-rw------- 1 root root 16384  7월 26 00:55 index-0--23645261368052429.wt
-rw------- 1 root root  4096  7월 26 00:55 index-1--23645261368052429.wt
-rw------- 1 root root  4096  7월 26 00:56 index-2--23645261368052429.wt
-rw------- 1 root root 16384  7월 26 00:55 index-3--23645261368052429.wt
-rw------- 1 root root 32768  7월 26 00:56 index-4--23645261368052429.wt
drwx------ 2 root root  4096  7월 26 00:55 journal
-rw------- 1 root root     6  7월 26 00:55 mongod.lock
-rw------- 1 root root 36864  7월 26 00:57 sizeStorer.wt
-rw------- 1 root root   114  7월 26 00:45 storage.bson
```

**root@ubuntu:/var/lib/mongodb# ls -al**

```
합계 2468
drwxr-xr-x  4 mongodb mongodb   4096  7월 26 01:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 48 root    root      4096  7월 21 20:50 ..
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb     46  7월 18  2018 WiredTiger
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb     21  7월 18  2018 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   1056  7월 26 01:05 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 192512  7월 26 01:05 WiredTiger.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb   4096  7월 26 01:03 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  16384  7월 26 01:03 collection-0--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-10-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-12-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-14-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-16-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-18-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:04 collection-2--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  16384  7월 26 01:03 collection-20-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  45056  7월 26 01:03 collection-22-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-24-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-26-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 196608  7월 26 01:03 collection-28-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-30-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  61440  7월 26 01:03 collection-32-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  24576  7월 26 01:03 collection-34-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  32768  7월 26 01:03 collection-36-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 151552  7월 26 01:03 collection-38-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  20480  7월 26 01:03 collection-4--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 114688  7월 26 01:03 collection-40-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  45056  7월 26 01:03 collection-42-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-44-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-46-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:03 collection-6-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 147456  7월 26 01:03 collection-8-6605498715908891783.wt
drwx------  2 mongodb mongodb   4096  7월 26 01:27 diagnostic.data
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  16384  7월 26 01:03 index-1--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  1월  8  2019 index-11-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  1월 31 00:32 index-13-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  16384 12월 16  2018 index-15-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864 12월 16  2018 index-17-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  32768 12월 19  2018 index-19-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  16384 12월 19  2018 index-21-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 25 00:05 index-23-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 10 16:36 index-25-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  2월 26 10:29 index-27-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  69632  7월 25 10:00 index-29-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:04 index-3--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  2월 26 11:20 index-31-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  32768  2월 18 11:25 index-33-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  24576  4월  9 21:59 index-35-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  32768  2월 21 17:50 index-37-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  53248  7월 21 09:00 index-39-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  53248  6월 10 22:36 index-41-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 25 00:00 index-43-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  5월 13 10:02 index-45-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  4월  9 16:10 index-47-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  20480  8월  9  2018 index-5--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  20480  7월 26 01:04 index-6--6413199990932768598.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  2월 26 13:46 index-7-6605498715908891783.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864 10월 25  2018 index-9-6605498715908891783.wt
drwx------  2 mongodb mongodb   4096  7월 26 01:04 journal
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb      4  7월 26 01:03 mongod.lock
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  36864  7월 26 01:05 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb    114  7월 18  2018 storage.bson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I start mongodb I just typed `mongod` then I cannot find database.

But when I start mongodb like `service mongod start` I can see database.

I don't know why and what's diffrent between two, but second way I can see db.

Comment: The difference is that when you start `mongod` without a config file it will use default values including a [`dbPath` of `/data/db`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath). When you start MongoDB using a `service` definition, this loads a config file which sets some path values to those created during the package installation. If you installed the [official MongoDB packages for Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), the service definition will use `/etc/mongod.conf` and a `dbPath` of `/var/lib/mongodb`.